# img src returning 404 when path is correct

Tags: django

html template:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static image_url %}">
<p>{{ quote }}</p>
```

view:

```
def makeImage(request):
    image = request.FILES['image']
    quote = request.POST['quote']
    fs = FileSystemStorage(location="static/")
    filename = fs.save(image.name, image)
    image_url = fs.url(filename)
    return render(request, 'app/makeImage.html', {'image_url': image_url, 'quote': quote})
```

error

```
[05/May/2022 15:56:13] "POST /app/makeImage/ HTTP/1.1" 200 49
[05/May/2022 15:56:13] "GET /static/Space_Yzkaqwp.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1810
```

...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Fixed pretty much immediately, had to add STATICFILES_DIRS to settings.py